Complexification of the nilradical of a real Lie algebra
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional real Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{g}^{\mathbb{C}}$ denote its complexification.
Is it true that the nilradical of  $\mathfrak{g}^{\mathbb{C}}$ is the complexification of the nilradical of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{nil}(\mathfrak{g}^{\mathbb{C}})=\mathfrak{nil}(\mathfrak{g})^{\mathbb{C}}$?
I have tried tried to analyse the case when $\mathfrak{g}$ is a solvable Lie algebra, because in such case I know
$$
\mathfrak{nil}(\mathfrak{g}^{\mathbb{C}}) = \{ X \in \mathfrak{g}^{\mathbb{C}} : \operatorname{ad}_{\mathfrak{g}^{\mathbb{C}}}(X) \mbox{ is a nilpotent linear map}\}
$$
by using Lie's Theorem on complex solvable Lie algebras, but I haven't been able to conclude anything so far.
Any help will be really appreciated.

This looks like the same fact for the solvable radical, see this duplicate.

Bourbaki proves this in ridiculous generality in their first volume on Lie Groups and Algebras (§ 4 no. 5): For any field extension $L|K$ and a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over $K$, the scalar extension of the nilradical is contained in the nilradical of the scalar extension. The other inclusion holds if the field extension is separable (e.g. in characteristic $0$, e.g. $\mathbb C|\mathbb R$), which they prove by referring to a corresponding theorem for associative algebras.

That being said, the crucial step in the proof in our special case would just be to write any element of the scalar extension as $1\otimes n_1 + i\otimes n_2$ as in the post linked to by Dietrich Burde.

Thank you so much !!! ❤️
